# Why is my Rails app hanging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, worker

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2.0. Recently, I have noticed that my app will hang for long periods of time when a certain worker is working. This is an app that has been under development for several years and I have never seen this sort of hanging behavior before (nor am I unfortunately completely aware of what changes I've made since it was last not hanging).

What I mean by "hang" is: No pages will load (no controllers can be reached, and even the default homepage which is basically a static page won't load). None of my logs will update. Standard output is not being written to. The application also has many background worker processes (managed by Resque), which also appear to be hung.

I have looked at top and netstat and various other Unix utilities and I don't see anything alarming there, either.

Finally, I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning but this application is running via Foreman on an EC2 instance.

**EDIT:** I don't believe that it is query related, because nothing abnormal shows up on top. Also, I'm a little inexperienced with rails, but each job has its own entry in the process table, if that helps.

Comment: Are the workers one off or is it using the same thread as the application? I would assume the hang is due to an increased work load for the worker because as the lifespan of the application increases generally so does the database and the jobs workers must do.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the first question, but I am fairly sure that this is not a simple issue of job size increasing.

Comment: Perhaps a long running database query that locks an important table like `users`? That would lead to a situation in which all other processes have to wait for the one job to finish.

Comment: I'll further look into the query logs, but the tables that this job is interacting with are relatively small.

Comment: Also, that still doesn't seem to explain why even the home page (which is just static content, no database calls) hangs.

Comment: My first question pertains to how your workers are running. If your workers are running in the same thread as the application itself then the rest of the application will have to wait until the worker has completed. You can run workers in a one off configuration where the worker has its own thread to run in thus freeing up the application thread to run the application. As for setting this up though I am not very familiar with EC2. Although this doesn't pertain directly to your case [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/code/1151) seems like it might help you get an idea of "workers" in EC2

Comment: The workers are each running in their own process (children of the Foreman process).